# Como hacer un listado mensual en SQL server?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, date

Buenas quisiera que me ayudarán, tengo una tabla con fechas...la fecha máxima es '2054-04-12' y la fecha mínima es fecha actual, todo esto está en la misma columna.

Quisiera hacer un listado hasta la fecha máxima, no sé si puede hacer como un contador con For

```
Select Nummes, fechaV from junio3
```

Aclaro un poco en la columna de `fechaV` hay distintas fechas y no son incrementales .. necesito hacer una lista incrementar mensual de esa columna

Ejemplo

```
FechaV
2023-06-07
2023-07-07
2023-08-07
...
2054-04-12
```

Estos son los datos que tengo actualmente
[image: lo siento por mi formular la pregunta, estoy desde el celular y es más complicado editar con fotos]

Comment: Un listado hasta la fecha máxima? Será `Select distinct fechaV from junio3`? O lo que quieres es listar todos los días desde hoy hasta la fecha máxima? A como está escrita tu pregunta no está claro lo que necesitas.

Comment: tambien podría ser "Select FechaV from junio3 group by FechaV order by 1 asc", pero, depende de que es lo que necesites, que necesitas hacer con esas fechas?

Comment: @Arriel sus respuestas solamente me hacen agrupaciónes... quiero un listado mensual...en la columna hay varías fechas ramdoms y no está de forma incrementar por eso la pregunta... mejorare un poco la redacción

Comment: Hola @CristhianCoria, por que no utilizas la opción [edit] y agregas un ejemplo. Los datos que obtenes actualmente (_no todos, con un par alcanza_) y como quisieras que sea el resultado.

Comment: Buscar "create a list of days between two dates sql" en google me regaló [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server) de stackoverflow en inglés. la versión del CTE recursivo funciona de maravilla. Te recomiendo trabajar en tus habilidades de investigación; sólo tomó veinte segundos encontrarlos en google.

Comment: igual revisa los [Partition by](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-partition-by-clause-overview/), si lo que necesitas es agrupar por mes y ordenar

Comment: @Arriel te comento que ya había encontrado esa respuesta y no me dió la solución esperada, o quizás la estoy implementando mal

Comment: No sé qué es una "lista incremental mensual" Las posibilidades son muchas, por poner ejemplos, podría ser una lista que incluya todas las fechas en orden cronológico (como sugiere tu ejemplo), pero podría ser una que muestre solo una fecha por cada mes. Esa fecha podría ser la más baja/alta en el mes, o la más cercana al centro del mes. También podría ser que nos muestre el primer día del mes y la cantidad de fechas que tiene la lista. Creo que podrías explicarlo con palabras o con un ejemplo, dejando una lista de datos y el resultado exacto que esperas producir con esos datos.

Comment: @jachguate solamente me interesa el incremento mensual...como si fuera un plan de pagos de un crédito ..el día me da igual ...intente con DATEADD pero eso tendría que hacerlo Miles de veces hasta llegar la fecha máxima (2054) y no se si se puede usar una especie de contador (for) en una consulta para obtener lo que quiero

Comment: Y, en todo esto, qué tiene que ver la tabla donde ya tienes fechas, entonces? Una cosa es generar un listado de meses, partiendo de la fecha inicial y una cantidad de meses o una fecha final, y otra es procesar una tabla para obtener un listado mensual de las fechas que contiene.

Comment: Tengo esa tabla como referencia, ya que la fecha máxima es el tope que debe llegar las mensualidades, y bueno estoy un poco perdido para generar dicha lista

Comment: Sugiero edites la pregunta y mejores su redacción, dejando claro que lo que buscas es generar una lista. Está bien que menciones la tabla si lo que quieres es insertar los datos en ella, pero si no, es mejor obviarla por completo, pues no tiene relevancia. No olvides dejar bien claro qué parámetros tienes de entrada, si es la fecha inicial y el número de meses, o la fecha inicial y final, etc. y un ejemplo claro de la salida que esperas generar, no necesariamente todas las filas, pero lo suficiente para comprender el problema. Si haces eso, dejame una mención y veo de escribir una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo, es usando una tabla de números. Las tablas de números (*Tally tables* en inglés) son tablas con una sola columna con números consecutivos. Estas tablas permiten repetir filas, aumentar valores y eliminar la necesidad de bucles.

Una forma eficiente de hacer una tabla de números que no requiere lectura de disco es usando CTEs en cascada.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

Para que sea más fácil y eficiente, vamos a convertirla en una función que pueda recibir un rango.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally](  
    @Start  bigint,  
    @End    bigint  
)  
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
RETURN  
WITH   
E(n) AS(  
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)  
),  
E2(n) AS(  
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b  
),  
E4(n) AS(  
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b  
),  
cteTally(n) AS(  
    SELECT TOP(@End - @Start + 1)  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + @Start - 1 n  
    FROM E4  
)  
SELECT n  
FROM cteTally;
```

Esta función la unimos a la tabla por medio de `APPLY` y tenemos el consecutivo  de meses.

```
-- Generamos datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE #Prueba(
    ID      int IDENTITY, --Esta es solo para ordenar el resultado y visualizar mejor
    Nummes  int, 
    fechaV  date
);
INSERT INTO #Prueba( Nummes, fechaV)
VALUES( 3,   '2023-09-29'),
      ( 138, '2034-12-10'),
      ( 117, '2033-03-09'),
      ( 29,  '2025-11-26'),
      ( 17,  '2024-11-10');

-- Creamos la consulta
SELECT p.Nummes, --Cantidad de meses
       p.fechaV, --fecha inicial
       m.n, --Numero de instancia del mes
       DATEADD( MM, m.n - 1, p.fechaV) mes --Consecutivo de meses. Restamos 1 para mostrar también la fecha inicial como uno de los meses.
FROM #Prueba p
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally( 1, p.Nummes) m
ORDER BY ID, mes --Ordenamos para evaluar el resultado, pero es innecesario.
```